# Is it sunnah to say Alhamdulillah when someone says how are you?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, sunnah

Is it instructed by the prophet to say Alhamdulillah When someone asks you how are you? Is it sunnah?

Comment: The prophet did began every lecture by giving thanks to Allah. And I do recall whenever the prophet or his family were asked they did such. But I don't have enough references to back that up. Yet I don't think if one doesn't do such, like he's not disobeying the Sunnah. It's just highly recommended...